# Select a specific row's childs with a specific class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-selectors

I want to select all  elements which has a class "szoveg"

```
<tr>
<td><input type=hidden name=sss value=M></td>
<td><input type=hidden![enter image description here][1] name=mmm value=U></td>
<td><input class="szoveg" type=text name=x3 maxlength=5 size=31></td>
<td><input class="szoveg" type=text name=x4 maxlength=20 size=52></td>
<td><input class="szoveg" type=text name=x5 maxlength=20 size=43></td>
<td><input class="szoveg" type=text name=x6 maxlength=200 size=75></td>
<td colspan=2><input class="gomb" type=submit value=New onclick="changeColor2()"></td>
</tr>
```

I can select the **specific row** with `$("#megye_tablazat tr").eq(3)`, but cannot select the `input elements` where the class is `szoveg`.
How can I achieve it with JQuery?

And I checked, it is here, in the document tree...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYlWT.png]

Comment: Why do you have hidden inputs directly nested within the `tr`? Just because they're hidden doesn't mean you can put them there.

Comment: Because it will be a needed information in a form submit or ajax submit... But that's not the point... 
More of that i do not write this code, i just need to expand it with a functionality

Comment: @BoltClock is sugesting, that you should put it somwhere else, for example before the table daclaration.

Comment: Only `td` and `th` elements can be children of `tr` elements. The browser will most likely correct you invalid HTML and move the `input` elements before or after the table, or just ignore them. Always create valid HTML! Aside from that it is not clear what your problem is. Which `input` do you want to access? What do you want to do?

Comment: Ok, just to be clear i do not write this code: S and this is live at some company, and i think i do not have a right to refact it just to extend it with some functionality...

Comment: As said, if you are trying to access the hidden inputs in that row, then you cannot do it. Those inputs *won't be there* in the final document because it is *invalid HTML*. Accessing the inputs in the tables cells won't be a problem though.

Comment: That's weird because i am 1000% hundred sure they do it, and that's the way the form submit is working at this company...

Comment: then tell your company the way they are doing it is wrong.. the html is invalid..you cannot have `input` inside `<tr>` tag without `<td>`

Comment: Well, have a look at this simple example and tell me whether the input is inside the black border or not: http://jsfiddle.net/UESnH/ Also do a right click on the input element and select "Inspect element" to see where in tree the element is. The only way to achieve what you want is fix the HTML.

Comment: This is invalid markup, `<input type="hidden"` should also be in `td`.

Comment: Ok, so let's make something's clear here: I do not care about this  is valid or not, because that's the way it is work.. And it is a static value... And i am 100% sure it can be submitted because that's the way the system works... Too bad, nobody answered to my selector question (ok somebody did)... But thanks everybody to make my life harder: ) Anyway i will escalate this issue, but the problem (again) has NOTHING to do with this...

Comment: ok, but i will change just to make everybody's life better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `find()`

```
 $("#megye_tablazat tr").eq(3).find('input.szoveg').each(function(){....});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use each() function:

```
$("input.szoveg"). each (function() {     
    // in here, you have the current input as this. fe:
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: this would be a good solution, if i do not have a hundreds of row in this page and i do not want a specific row!